# ¿Cómo puedo sincronizar una hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets a Calendar con celdas vacías?

Tags: javascript, script, calendar

Soy nuevo entre los scripts de Sheets y no logro sincronizar a Google Calendar con filas vacías. Les pido que me puedan orientar. No se genera ningún error pero no me copia los datos a Calendar. Adjunto imagen. Gracias.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPtWj.png)

[He copiado las instrucciones](https://stackoverflow.com) pero no lo he conseguido

Antes me generava las fechas en Calendar devolviendo el error (String, String, String). Evidentemente tambien se detenía el script al llegar a las filas vacías. Adjunto imagen.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Calendari')
      .addItem('Crear Visites', 'Crearvisites')
      .addToUi(); }



//CREACIÓ DE VISITES CALENDAR


   function Crearvisites() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var configCalendar = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    var calendarID = configCalendar.getRange("D2").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:D500").getValues();
    
    for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];

    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var title= shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
}
   }
```

Copio el código. Gracias.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Calendari')
      .addItem('Crear Visites', 'Crearvisites')
      .addToUi(); }



//CREACIÓ DE VISITES CALENDAR


   function Crearvisites() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var configCalendar = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    var calendarID = configCalendar.getRange("D2").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:D500").getValues();
    
    for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
      var slot = signups[x];
      var startTime = slot[0];
      var endTime = slot[1];
      var title= slot[2];
      if (title && startTime && endTime) {  
        if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).length == 0) {  
          eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podemos modificar y programar codigo, pero no creo que podamos hacerlo en imagenes. Porfavor coloca el codigo en la pregunta:D

Comment: Copio el código. Gracias

Comment: Sigo sin haberlo conseguido. Alguien me puede orientar? Gracias

Comment: Roger lo que pasa es que todavia alguien que sepa del tema todavia no ha visto tu pregunta, intenta ponerle la etiqueta javascript a tu pregunta(porque script y calendar no dice el lenguaje  usas), ya me he desocupado, eere la documentacion y si consigo respuesta te aviso sino no digo nada:D